# How to set ssh access for user on debian?

Tags: linux, debian, ssh

I set groups:

```
usermod -G ssh username
```

and then I've checked account info:

```
id username
```

the result is:

```
uid=1000(username) gid=1001(username) groups=100(username)
```

Anyway if I try to login using ssh I get an error:
Permission denied, please try again.

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE1:**
if I run /usr/sbin/sshd -d the result is:

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
Set /proc/self/oom_adj from 0 to -17
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.
Cannot bind any address.
```

**UPDATE2:**
The log is:

```
Dec 29 22:06:44 p148401 sshd[32456]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=changed_host  user=username
Dec 29 22:06:47 p148401 sshd[32456]: Failed password for username from 8*.*.*.* port 52765 ssh2
```

**UPDATE3:**

```
root@p148401:/etc/init.d# sudo service ssh stop
Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
root@p148401:/etc/init.d# /usr/sbin/sshd -d
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
Set /proc/self/oom_adj from 0 to -17
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
```

And doesn't respond anymore...needs to restart

..and ssh config is here http://codepad.org/8bynXZQC

Comment: please give the output of `/var/log/auth.log` when you get `Permission Denied` and also give output when you try to login with `ssh -v` running ssh in verbose mode or run the server in debug mode stop sshd and run start it like this `/usr/sbin/sshd -d`.Please post these logs here.

Comment: I think that the sshd was not started yet.

Comment: added updates, but don't understand what does these log mean

Comment: stop the sshd service by using `sudo service ssh stop` and then run `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d`

Comment: also please give your `sshd_config` file

Comment: Anthony: After you run the server with `/usr/sbin/sshd -d` Try login into the server from the client.you will find logs in the terminal. then you can cancel it with Ctrl+C and start ssh with `sudo service ssh start`

Comment: Remove `#` in front of `#PasswordAuthentication yes`
SSH support multiple ways to authenticate users, the most common one is by asking a login and a password but you can also authenticate user a login and a public key. If you set PasswordAuthentication to no, you will no longer be able to use a login and password to authenticate and must use a login and public key instead (if `PubkeyAuthentication` is set to yes)

Comment: damned I cannot enter to ssh under root now-) Tried to reboot server. Doesn't help

Comment: @Anthony Then you need either direct access to the server or a serial console access by your hosting provider.